# How to get domain sid from domain dns name?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have the dns name of an Active Directory domain and I would like to get the domain sid for this domain. How can I do this?

I already have the following:

```
var domainContext =
    new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainDnsName);
var domain = Domain.GetDomain(domainContext);
var dc = domain.DomainControllers.OfType<DomainController>().FirstOrDefault();
```

But I'm a little stuck where to go from here (or maybe I'm following the wrong route).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you want is something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry domainEntry = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();
byte[] domainSid = domainEntry.Properties["objectSID"].Value as byte[];
SecurityIdentifier strongDomainSid = new SecurityIdentifier(domainSid, 0);
```

Comment: That won't work: `Domain` doesn't have a method `GetDirectoryEntry()`. `DomainController` does, but it returns a `DirectoryEntry` without an `objectSid`...

Comment: MSDN says it does - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.aspx. If not for whatever reason, it's trivial to get yourself. Just create a new DirectoryEntry for the DN of the domain (e.g. var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=mydomain,dc=com"). You should be able to get the DN off the domain object if nothing else.

Comment: Hm, overlooked that one... Not sure though if the default naming context has an objectSID. Will look into that after the weekend. Thanks sofar!

Comment: It does - every domain has a SID

Comment: It works. Weird that I had overlooked the `Domain.GetDirectoryEntry` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in native code.

1. Build the ldap query string for the domain you want. E.g. "LDAP://fabrikam.com" (It doesn't have to be in distinguished form, e.g. "LDAP://DC=fabrikam,DC.com" <sup>[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772352(v=vs.85).aspx)</sup>)

   ```
   String path = "LDAP://fabrikam.com";
   ```
2. Get the `ADs` object that represents the domain

   ```
   IADs domain = ADsGetObject(path);
   ```
3. Get the `objectSid` byte array property of the domain object:

   ```
   Variant objectSid = domain.Get("objectSid");
   ```
4. Convert the binary sid into a string:

   ```
   Pointer p = SafeArrayAccessData(objectSid);
   String domainSid = ConvertSidToStringSid(p);
   ```

Which returns you the nice domain sid:

```
String GetDomainSid(String domainName)
{
   Variant objectSid = ADSGetObject(domainName).Get("objectSid");
   Pointer p = SafeArrayAccessData(objectSid);
   String domainSid = ConvertSidToStringSid(p);       
   SafeArrayUnaccessData(objectSid);

   return domainSid;
}

GetDomainSid("fabrikam.com") ==> "S-1-5-21-1708537768-844245398-2146844275"
```